# Ajax working but getting redirected to processing page php

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to submit a form in php using Ajax, but I don't know why its not working out. The console logs in my ajax are executing but I'm getting redirected to the page where my form data is processed and inserted into database!

Form

```
<form id='formData' action="process/profile-settings" method="POST">
         <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Name</label>
                   <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->userName(); ?>" disabled />
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                   <label>Description/Bio</label>
                   <input type="text" name="bio" class="form-control" value="" />
              </div>
          </div>
<button class="btn d-block mx-auto save" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Here is my ajax code

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
            console.log('readyyyy');
            $("#formData").on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('donwwwww');
            var data = $("#formData").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                url: '../user/process/profile-settings.php',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'post',
                success: (response) => {
                    console.log('Doneeeee');
                },
                error: function(status, exception) {
                    alert('Exception:', exception);
                }
            });
        });
        });
```

Form Processing Code

```
<?php
    include_once '../../core/init.php';

    $dbqueries = new dbQueries;
    $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];

    if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        echo 'PHP';
        $bio = filter_var($_POST['bio'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        echo 'DOneeeeeee';
        if($dbqueries->Query('UPDATE users SET bio = ? WHERE id = ?', [$bio, $userId])){
           return 1;
        }
    }


?>
```

**UPDATED**

My form is processed in the 'process/profile-settings'. I've removed .php extension using .htaccess. Whenever I click on save the ajax is processed and I'm getting console.log but I'm getting redirected to the page where my form is processed!
Appreciate your help!

Comment: You need to prevent the submit on click by using preventDefault - $('.save').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();

Comment: Also you might want to fire on submit instead of click $("#formData").submit(function

Comment: Now I'm not gettting redirected but ajax is not working but I can get console log from success

Comment: There is a console.log (2nd line) that seems wrapping the entire Ajax call as it is not closed. Is it on purpose or you made a mistake when pasting it here?

Comment: Edited, I'm trying to find all the possible errors but nothing works, please help

Comment: You have no element with `id="save"`. You probably meant to use `$('#formData').on('submit', ...`

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is here, `$('#save').on('submit', function(e)`. You don't have a `#save` button or form, you have `.save`. Also, change it back to a `click` event then you don't need `e.preventDefault();`, but you need to specify the `type` as button to prevent the page from reloading.

```js
$('.save').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log('doneeee');
  var data = $("#formData").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'process/profile-settings.php',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='formData' action="process/profile-settings" method="POST">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $user->userName(); ?>" disabled />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Description/Bio</label>
      <input type="text" name="bio" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn d-block mx-auto save" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Didn't work, is there anything to do with my processing php file??

Comment: Need more information than "it didn't work." I know the code I posted works because I tested it. Check the network tab in developer tools, make sure it sent and that you're getting a response. You're probably not getting a response from your php script. If it sends, but there's no response, try doing a `var_dump()` from beginning to end until you find the problem area.

Comment: If you see that the request is being sent to `profile-settings.php`, this question is answered and you'll need to begin troubleshooting your server side code.

Comment: Tried some debugging, seems like my form isn't getting processed through ajax but works completely fine without ajax, any guess why it is not being process. I even tried to process the form in the same file i.e. where my main form is, but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    console.log('readyyyy');
    $("#formData").on('submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('donwwwww');
        var data = $("#formData").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '../user/process/profile-settings.php',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'post'
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            console.log('Doneeeee');
        }).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, but I think the problem is in my processing file because ajax is working fine. Please help me out find it!!

Comment: @Cybil - Your question is not about PHP, it's about AJAX. If you're having a PHP issue ask a different question.

Comment: @Cybil can you please share you process file

Comment: I've shared it, check the updated question. Thankyou